# Type not assignable with object in TS

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've got a error but I don't understand why:

```
Type '"New Choice"' is not assignable to type '"Yes" | "No"'.ts(2322)
test.ts(17, 14): The expected type comes from property 'text' which is declared here on type '{ text: 
"Yes"; } | { text: "No"; }'
```

I'm tryng to define multiple pararms but with the objects I 've some errors

This is my code

```
    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

survey:{
    name:"My Quick Survey",
    questionnaires:[{
    question:"Ready for a quick survey?",
    multi:true,
    choices:[
        {text:"Yes"},
        {text:"No"}
    ]
    }]  
}

results:{
    success:"",
    error:""
}

addchoice(i) {
    this.survey.questionnaires[i].choices.push({text:"New Choice"})
    // I've got error here
}

removechoice(i,j) {
    this.survey.questionnaires[i].choices.splice(j,1)
}
addquestion() {
    this.survey.questionnaires.push({
    question:"Next question?",   // I've got error here
    multi:true,
    choices:[
        {text:"Choice1"},    // I've got error here
        {text:"Choice2"}     // I've got error here
    ]
    })
}

}
```

How can I resolve this error ?
Thanks

Comment: You are declaring all the variables wrong. It should be `survey = ...` When you use `:` the compiler thinks you are declaring a type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of your class, you're declaring survey as this:

```
survey:{
    name:"My Quick Survey",
    questionnaires:[{
    question:"Ready for a quick survey?",
    multi:true,
    choices:[
        {text:"Yes"},
        {text:"No"}
    ]
    }]  
}
```

This only declares a type, not a value. What you probably want to do is initialize an attribute. For this, you should replace : by =

```
survey = {
    name:"My Quick Survey",
    questionnaires:[{
    question:"Ready for a quick survey?",
    multi:true,
    choices:[
        {text:"Yes"},
        {text:"No"}
    ]
    }]  
}
```

You'e also got the same issue with results

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
survey = {
    name: "My Quick Survey",
    questionnaires: [{
    question: "Ready for a quick survey?",
    multi: true,
    choices: [
            {text:"Yes"},
            {text:"No"}
        ]
    }]  
}
```

You probably thought you were doing an attribution to the property survey, but you used `:` instead of `=`, so this is not an attribution, it's a type declaration.